# Compute action of the gauge group in deformation theory of an algebra

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, ra.rings-and-algebras, complex-geometry, homological-algebra, deformation-theory

I am working on [Balazs Szendroi's introduction to deformation theory](https://people.maths.ox.ac.uk/szendroi/defth.pdf), but I got stuck on the exercise on the bottom of page 6.

Consider a vector space $A$ with a multiplication $m$ that makes it into an associative algebra. A deformed multiplication is given by $m + f$, where $f$ must satisfy $df + \frac12[f,f] = 0$ in order to preserve associativity.

Now for any $g \in \operatorname{Hom}(A,A)$, define $T=\exp(g) \in GL(A)$, and $T$ acts on $m+f$ as $T \circ (m+f)(a,b) = T(m+f)(T^{-1}a, T^{-1}b)$.

Show that the corresponding action on $f$ is $T\circ f = TfT^{-1} + TdT^{-1}$, "where the product maps here are the appropriate compositions". I think this means that $TfT^{-1}(a,b) = Tf(T^{-1}a, T^{-1}b)$.

My attempt:

$m+f$ corresponds to $f$ by subtracting $m$. So we need to show that $$
T\circ(m+f) -m = T\circ f + TdT^{-1}.$$
which reduces to 
$$
T \circ m -m = T[m,T^{-1}]
$$
Acting on $(a,b)$, this is
$$
Tm(T^{-1}a, T^{-1}b) - m(a,b) = T\left(\pm m(T^{-1}a,b) \pm m(a,T^{-1}b) \pm T^{-1}m(a,b)\right) 
$$
(where the $\pm$ are because the signs are annoying, I'll be happy to solve this mod 2).

These look kind of similar, but definitely not the same. For example, even taking $g=0$, $T=id$, it doesn't work out. I must be missing something...